# Rectangular overview with specific size, location and heading on MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, geolocation, location, mkmapview

I have a question which involves drawing a rectangular overlay on an `MKMapView`.

I get the currect user location (coordinate), then I would like to draw a rectangular overlay on the `MKMapView` where the user location is the bottom center coordinate. The rectangular overlay has to be 10 meters wide (5 meters on both sides of the coördinate) and 100 meters high.

The `MKMApView` rotates as the user rotates so the rectangle should always point the way the user is heading.

Does anybody know how to do this? I'm kind of stuck on this one.

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you able to create the rectangle? You should include the code you have as of right now.

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks I think if allready got it sorted.